# Ajax submits the form even if its not validated with bootstrap validation

Tags: ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I've a `form` with `bootstrap` which works fine. And jQuery Validation works fine.  When it comes to `ajax` submit code, there is something wrong. Submit works even if the `form` is not validated.

Lets say I left one field empty and pressed submit, it highlights the error on the empty field but ajax still submits the `form`.

How can I stop action and ask for validation?

This is the `form` markup:

```
<form id="booking" method="post" class="form" action="" >
    ....some input fields here....
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary">Book Now</button>
</form>
```

This is the jQuery Validation:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {minlength: 2, maxlength: 40, required: true}, 
        lastname: {minlength: 2, maxlength: 40, required: true}, 
        email: {email: true, required: true}, 
        country: {required: true}, 
        mobile: {minlength: 2, maxlength: 40, required: true}, 
        address: {minlength: 3, required: true}
    },
});
```

This part is the `ajax()` submit:

```
$('#booking').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this); 
    var post_url = form.attr('action'); 
    var post_data = form.serialize();
    $('#loader', form).html('<img src="http://www.fethiye-tours.com/assets/images/lightbox/loading.gif" /> Please Wait...');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.fethiye-tours.com/book.php',
        data: post_data,
        success: function(msg) {
            $(form).fadeOut(500, function(){
                form.html(msg).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: Must your `.validate()` call be written without any line breaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"submit works even if the form is not validated"*

That's because your custom `.on('submit')` handler is over-riding the jQuery Validation plugin's built-in submit handler.

Referring to [the documentation for the jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/),

> **submitHandler** (default: native form submit)
>  Type: Function()
>  Callback for handling the actual submit when the form
>   is valid. Gets the **`form`** as the only argument. *Replaces the default
>   submit*. **The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is
>   validated**.

In other words, any `.ajax()` code goes inside of the `submitHandler` callback function, which only fires when the form is valid.  So get rid of your entire `.on('submit')` handler function and do this instead...

(*BTW:  properly indented/formatted code is better for everyone to read and troubleshoot*)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#booking').validate({  // <- attach '.validate()' to your form
        // any rules, options, and callbacks,
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                // minlength: 2,
                // maxlength: 40,
                rangelength: [2,40], // <- combines minlength and maxlength rules
                required: true
            },
            //  more rules,
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // <- only fires when form is valid
            $('#loader', $(form)).html('<img src="http://www.fethiye-tours.com/assets/images/lightbox/loading.gif" /> Please Wait...');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://www.fethiye-tours.com/book.php',
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(msg) {
                    $(form).fadeOut(500, function(){
                        $(form).html(msg).fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            });            // <- end '.ajax()'
            return false;  // <- block default form action
        }                  // <- end 'submitHandler' callback
    });                    // <- end '.validate()'

});                        // <- end DOM ready handler
```

It doesn't look like you need the `post_url` variable since you're already declaring the `url` within your `.ajax()`.  Might as well save a line and do the same with `post_data` too.